# Convert formula as string to function in Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, graph

I have a problem with this code.
I want to send a function (for example: x**2) to this class and have it show me a graph of it.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

class diagram(tk.Frame):
    step=100
    point_lst=[]
    def __init__(self, master=None, fkt="x**2"):
        self.fkt=fkt
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.cv=tk.Canvas(self, width=600, height=600, bg="#F00011")
        self.cv.pack()
        self.update_scale()
        self.fkt()

    def fkt(self):
        for x in range(0, 100):
            self.point_lst.append((x+10, self.fkt+10))

        print(self.point_lst)

        for i in range(1, 99, 1):
            self.cv.create_line(self.point_lst[i-1][0], 600-self.point_lst[i-1][1], self.point_lst[i][0], 600-self.point_lst[i][1])

    def update_scale(self):
        #print("up")
        self.cv.delete(tk.ALL)

        self.cv.create_line(10, 590, 590, 590, width=3)
        self.cv.create_line(10, 10, 10, 590, width=3)
        #scale on bot
        for x in range(10, 590, self.step):
            self.cv.create_line(x, 590, x, 580)
        #scale on side
        for y in range(10, 590, self.step):
            self.cv.create_line(10, y, 20, y)


root=tk.Tk()
app=diagram(root)
app.mainloop()
```

The problem is in the method `fkt()` where it should add the points to the list `self.point_lst`. How can I achieve that it calculates the given function?

PS: The +10 I added is for graphical causes. You can ignore it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When asking a question you should be a bit more specific about what you have tried so far and why it did not solve your problem. Furthermore, when asking a programming related question, posting a bit of example code to illustrate your difficulties and get others started helping you goes a long way. You should checkout the official ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post as well! I recommend that you do that first, have a think about how to improve your question, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the big picture, the function you're looking for is `eval()`.  Unfortunately, ***it's not a safe function*** .  With the string formula embedded in your code, you're OK, but once you start getting that string from a user via a tkinter `Entry` box then you have a problem.  As your user can type ***anything*** and get your code to evaluate it.  E.g. allow them to delete all your files.

Making it safer is up to you: you can scan the string to ensure it only contains `x` and an allowed set of operators; you could predefine all the formulas they can graph in a `dict`; etc.  Some folks might claim that `ast.literal_eval()` will take care of the safety issue -- it won't work for your purpose.

In the small picture, you've a bug in your `__init__` function as `fkt` is a *variable*, a *member* and a *method* name.  This keeps your code from running so I've renamed one of them in my rework of your code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

class diagram(tk.Frame):
    STEP = 100
    WIDTH = 600
    HEIGHT = 600
    BORDER = 15
    TICK = 10

    def __init__(self, master=None, fkt="2 * x"):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.fkt_string = fkt
        self.cv = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.WIDTH + self.BORDER, height=self.HEIGHT + self.BORDER, bg="#FFAAAA")
        self.cv.pack()
        self.pack()
        self.update_scale()
        self.fkt()

    def fkt(self):
        point_lst = []

        for x in range(0, 100):
            point_lst.append((x + self.BORDER, self.HEIGHT - eval(self.fkt_string)))

        for i in range(1, 100):
            self.cv.create_line(point_lst[i - 1][0], point_lst[i - 1][1], point_lst[i][0], point_lst[i][1])

    def update_scale(self):
        self.cv.delete(tk.ALL)

        self.cv.create_line(self.BORDER, self.HEIGHT, self.WIDTH + self.BORDER, self.HEIGHT, width=3)
        self.cv.create_line(self.BORDER, self.HEIGHT, self.BORDER, 0, width=3)

        # scale on bottom
        for x in range(self.BORDER, self.WIDTH + self.BORDER, self.STEP):
            self.cv.create_line(x, self.HEIGHT, x, self.HEIGHT - self.TICK)

        # scale on side
        for y in range(self.HEIGHT, 0, -self.STEP):
            self.cv.create_line(self.BORDER, y, self.BORDER + self.TICK, y)

root = tk.Tk()
app = diagram(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Graph of "2 * x":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @cdlane, this worked out great!

I also added a function to check for valid chars:

```
   def check_str(self):
        for char in self.fkt_string:
            if char not in self.allowed_str:
                print("Warning! Some of the strings may not be allowed")
                quit()
```

It checks, if the chars in the given formula match with the chars in self.fkt_string, and if not it quits the program.